# Как осуществить map-карту без перехода на другие страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть div с заданными размерами 800х300px. В нем должна быть map-карта, при нажатии на область которой, div должен загружать следующее (не обязательно по порядковому номеру) изображение без перехода на иные страницы.

[image]

вот, например, "**все это - картинка с каким-нибудь текстом**" имеет адрес "**images/1.png**", **область-ссылка1** имеет адрес на картинку с адресом "**images/4.png**", а **область-ссылка2** - "**images/15.png**". При нажатии на одну из областей, должна меняться "map-карта" на уже другую картинку со своими областями-ссылками без перехода на другие страницы сайта.

Как это осуществить? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Будем делать магическое извращение с присвоением атрибутов которые не снились даже HTML5

```
<img src="map.png" usemap="#map1" id="image" />

<map id="#map" name="map1">
    <area shape="rect" coords="25,36,114,98" href="http://google.com" rel="map2.png" usemap="#map2" />
</map>

<map id="#map2" name="map2">
    <area shape="rect" coords="25,36,114,98" href="http://google.com" />
</map>

<script>
    var area = document.getElementsByTagName('area');
    for(var i in area)
    {
        area[i].onclick = function()
        {
            if(this.getAttribute('rel') != null && this.getAttribute('usemap') != null)
            {
                document.getElementById('image').src = this.getAttribute('rel');
                document.getElementById('image').setAttribute('usemap', this.getAttribute('usemap'));
            }
            else
            {
                window.location.href = this.getAttribute('href');
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Я думаю разберетесь, за кроссбраузерность не ручаюсь.

Атрибуты для *`area`* **`rel`** и **`usemap`** хранят в себе информацию, которая должна быть изменена при клике.

Answer (score 1):

1. Вариант с автоподгрузкой через AJAX.
2. Написать скрипт, который будет заменять картинку, либо дописывать её в конец. Что-то `вроде document.getElementsByID(ID).innerHTML=img[i]`, где `ID` - идентификатор контейнера, где должна быть картинка, img[i] - массив с текстом кода картинок.
3. По умолчанию загрузить все картинки, но спрятать их от глаз через свойство `visibility:hidden;`. При помощи JS менять стиль на `visibility:visible`